# attached audio file using paperclip unclear what do with the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, paperclip

I have everything working and would like to get the audio to play or at least be able to click the url and have it play.  Not sure if this is expected behavior or not.

song.rb

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_attached_file :track, 
                     :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/posts/:id/:basename.:extension",
                     :url => "/assets/tracks/:id/:basename.:extension"
   validates :track,
   attachment_content_type: { content_type: [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]}
end
```

I am not sure if this is what correct way to format the URL or not, any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options here.

1) Use built-in HTML5 audio support. [Here is a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) to Mozilla's developer documentation. Note though that this method will depend on the format and the browser's support for that format. For example, I don't believe Firefox offers MP3 compatibility.

2) Use a plugin. One tool I have used in the past is [jplayer](http://jplayer.org/). You should be able to incorporate that and provide it with the url of your file and it will stream it to the user for you. Or, you can provide the link and anyone can download it and play it with software they have installed on their device.

Comment: never was able to get this to work, using jplayer kinda left me with the same questions, not knowing exactly what to do with the urls :(